# Make Python Class Methods searchable in Mongodb

Tags: python, class, mongodb, pymongo

I have a Mongodb collection and I have created a Python class for documents in the collection.  The class has some properties and methods which are not stored with the document.  Should I try and store them to make the properties searchable or should I not store them and search the objects in Python?

Here is an example:

```
# Child
class Child:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    @property
    def parent(self):
        try:
            return Parent(**db.Parents.find_one({'child':self._id}))
        except:
            return None

# Parent
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    @property
    def child(self):
        try:
            return Child(**db.Children.find_one({'parent':self._id}))
        except:
            return None
```

In this example, to search for all the children who's parent's name is "foo", I have to do this:

```
results = [Child(**c) for c in db.Children.find() if c.parent.name == 'foo']
```

This means I have to pull all the Children documents from Mongodb and search them.  Is it smarter to write the Parent data (or a subset of it) to the Child document, so I can use Mongodb to do the searching??  So my Child class could look like this:

```
# Child
class Child:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

    @property
    def parent_name(self):
        try:
            return db.Parents.find_one({'child':self._id})['name']
        except:
            return None

    def _save(self):
        # something like this to get and save all the properties
        data = {m[0]:getattr(self,m[0]) for m in inspect.getmembers(self)}
        db.Children.find_and_modify({'_id':self._id},{'$set':data},upsert=True)

# search
results = [Child(**c) for c in db.Children.find({'parent_name':'foo'})]
```

So the search is more efficient, but I think having to keep the Child objects updated could be painful and dangerous.  If I change the name of a Parent, I have to also rewrite its children.  Feels wrong.  Any better ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t have to load *all* `Children`.

```
parent_ids = db.Parents.find({'name': 'foo'}).distinct('_id')
children = db.Children.find({'parent': {'$in': parent_ids}})
```

(Also, why do you have both a `child` field on a parent *and* a `parent` field on a child?)

Comment: Thanks, that's true.  The parent/child is a feeble example.  There are no circular refs in my actual model.  Thanks again!